# vba coding to find match and copy range of data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel workbooks: 1- workbook has 19 columns and 8 rows and another workbook has 8 row names and 19 column names same like workbook1 but it doesnt contain any data. I need to copy range of data from workbook1 by exactly matching the rownames.
For example:
Workbook1:

```
icn id     location
1   125      M
2   123      F
3   132      G
4   145      H
5   145      I
```

Workbook2:

```
icn  id  Location
1
3
5
4
2
```

I tried coding but I was not able to get the range of data :

```
Sub UpdateW2()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Workbooks("workbookA.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("workbookB.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")


For Each c In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  FR = 0
  On Error Resume Next
  FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, 0)
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your references are a bit mixed up.

I've refactored your code to:

1. Loop over the rows in `wb2`, since this is the sheet you want to update
2. Look up each row in `wb1`
3. If found, copy columns `B` and `C` from `wb1` to `wb2`

Note that if `Application.Match` does not find a match, it does not throw a run time error, it returns an error *value* (on the other hand `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` does throw a run time error)

```
Sub UpdateW2()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim FR As Variant '<-- use Variant to allow catching a Error value
    Dim ws1Range As Range, ws2Range As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set w1 = Workbooks("workbookA.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Workbooks("workbookB.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set ws1Range = w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & w1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set ws2Range = w2.Range("A2", w2.Range("A" & w2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In ws2Range
        FR = Application.Match(c.Value, ws1Range, 0)
        If Not IsError(FR) Then
            ' Choose ONE of the next three blocks of code

            ' To copy formula and format
            'ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2).Copy Destination:=c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2)

            ' to copy only values
            'c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2) = ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2)

            ' To copy values and format
            c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2) = ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2)
            ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2).Copy
            c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you the code is working perfectly but there was one problem when the column is getting copied it loses its percentage format and only numbers get printed how to fix that? And also is it by any chance possible that I dont have to open workbook2 and it gets update and closes down by mentioning the path to the location of workbook2 ?

Comment: @vrushankshah see update re copy formats.  Re not opening workbook2: that's the book you are writing to, so no, you will need to open it.  If you meant not opening workbook1, then technically possible but possibly not worth the effort