# Excel VBA to match row data from two columns in two different workbooks and copy data

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different workbooks, wb1 and wb2.  I need a VBA script that will match row data from two columns in each workbook and then copy an offset cell from wb2 to wb1, looping through the entire workbook for each row.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901468/vba-coding-to-find-match-and-copy-range-of-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-wor) that is very close, however it doesn't look at data from both columns as a single piece of data to match.  Is this possible without merging the columns into a single cell first? Any assistance would be very appreciated.

Sample of what I need
[image: Sample of what I need]

Clarified picture of what I need
[image: Clarified picture of what I need]

Here is my modified code from the referenced post, many items are commented out as I've been trying to make it work and troubleshooting.

```
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim FR As Variant '<-- use Variant to allow catching a Error value
Dim ws1Range As Range, ws2Range As Range

Set w1 = Workbooks("Job Number with Labor Code.xlsx").Worksheets("LaborData")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Labor Report Project Hours.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws1Range1a = w1a.Range("C4", w1.Range("C" & w1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set ws1Range1b = w1b.Range("D4", w1.Range("D" & w1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set ws2Range = w2.Range("A8", w2.Range("B" & w1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'w1.Activate
'ws1Range.Select
'w2.Activate
'ws2Range.Select

For Each c In ws1Range
MsgBox (c.Value)
    FR = Application.Match(c.Value, ws2Range, 0)
    If Not IsError(FR) Then
      'MsgBox (c.Value)

'        ' To copy formula and format
'        'ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2).Copy Destination:=c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2)
            
'        ' to copy only values
'        'c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2) = ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2)
         'c.Cells.Select

'        ' To copy values and format
'        c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2) = ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2)
'        ws1Range.Cells(FR, 2).Resize(, 2).Copy
'        c.Cells(1, 2).Resize(, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Can you modify your image to have a little bit more meaningful data and more clearly state what you're trying to achieve? I see your diagram, but it's unclear what you want in the second column? The same as the first column?  Use different values to illustrate the objective (hard to tell with a bunch of zero values).

Comment: Hello, I have added a clarified image, data samples to match are highlighted and data to copy is shown better.  Thank you.

Comment: "Is this possible without merging the columns into a single cell first?"  Yes, yes it is.  You can compare strings, e.g., `stringOfTwoCells = Cells(a,1).Value & Cells(a,2).Value`, with an if statement or many other ways.  Even without VBA you can do this with a formula array, e.g., `={Match(A2&B2", Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0)}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) as a lookup with a composite key.

```vb
Option Explic
Sub macro1()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key As String, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' build lookup from sheet2
    Set w2 = Workbooks("Labor Report Project Hours.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRow = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ar = w2.Range("A1:C" & iLastRow).Value2
    
    For r = 8 To UBound(ar)
        key = ar(r, 1) & vbTab & ar(r, 2)
        If Len(key) > 1 Then ' skip blanks
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate key '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & r
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dict.Add key, ar(r, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' update sheet1
    Set w1 = Workbooks("Job Number with Labor Code.xlsx").Worksheets("LaborData")
    iLastRow = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 4 To iLastRow
        key = w1.Cells(r, "C") & vbTab & w1.Cells(r, "D")
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            w1.Cells(r, "F") = dict(key)
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Ended"
    
End Sub
```